# What does dereference of free object in Ghostscript mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, ghostscript, pdflatex

I am getting the following error when trying to compress a pdf with Ghostscript:

[image: Error message]

The output pdf has images and text missing. (Note: The missing images are pdf format themselves.)

My code is working as I am getting an output pdf. My input pdf is 30 MB and my output pdf is 9 MB, if this is required please indicate how I can share the files as they are too large to upload here.

[image: PDF File sizes]

Code to generate pdf:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['pdflatex', self.tex_file_location],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

Code to compress pdf:

```
subprocess.call([gs, '-sDEVICE=pdfwrite', '-dCompatibilityLevel=1.5',
                    '-dPDFSETTINGS={}'.format(quality[power]),
                    '-dNOPAUSE', '-dQUIET', '-dBATCH',
                    '-sOutputFile={}'.format(output_file_path),
                     input_file_path]
```

gs - location of Ghostscript Exe

input_file_path - String with the directory of input pdf.

output_file_path - String with the directory of output pdf.

Are there any options or settings I am missing? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It means something went wrong. An internal object was freed, and then something tried to drop a reference to it. It should not have  been freed if another object held a reference. You should open a bug report for this, though I'd suggest you first try and replicate it from the shell rather than your application. Attach the PDF file to the bug report and give the command line you used, please also state the version of Ghostscript being used. Note that Ghostscript's pdfwrite device doesn't compress PDF files. It produces new PDF files which, depending on the options used, may be smaller.

Comment: Ah, reading the text more carefully... The PDF file tried to use an object (1163) which has been marked in the cross reference table as being free (not used). You can't use free objects. So the PDF file is probably broken, I'd need to see the file to comment further. The images can't be 'pdf format' there is no 'pdf format' image type, PDF can read multiple types of bitmap image but it doesn't have a type of it's own.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this issue, not that it solved my problem, but I went down a rabbit hole and the only explanation I could find for my specific error was that there is a bug in Ghostscript when compressing pdfs that contain vector images or pdf images, not clear which.

I have given up on using Ghostscript at the moment.